# SVN Automatic merge to branch on check in

Tags: svn, scripting, merge

We use one branch for the our upcoming release, and trunk for the next release (later).

For example:
v1.1 -> v1.2 -> trunk
(Where v1.1 is in production, v1.2 is the upcoming release and trunk will turn into v1.3 closer to release).

While working on the upcoming release, we check in using SVN (TortoiseSVN). The problem with this is that all check ins must be manually merged to trunk if it's a change that will be relevant for later releases as well (Most changes in other words).

The problem is that when the developers are stressed, they tend to forget to merge. The consequence of this is that a fix which is done in a branch may need to be fixed again later because the developer forgot to merge the fix from branch to trunk

Is there a way to automatically merge the code to trunk when a check-in is made to the branch?

Answer (score 6):

Yes , it is possible , and there is an open source project that does it!

check out https://github.com/liveperson/Auto-Merger

we are constantly working with it and it saves so much time and helps avoiding all those missed merges bugs.

Answer (score 5):

No and I would strictly discourage from it. There are so many possible side effects that you will encouter with an automatic merging.

How would you resolve conflicts? The more development means more changes in branch and trunk, means more conflicts at merging. The merge must be done by hand.

What about unwanted merges? There are things (like changing version numbers, dependencies, etc.)  you don't want to merge back. With an automatic merge you had to reverse merge the merges, wich causes more confusion and work.

With the merge tracking feature of SVN 1.5 you'll get good information and see if someone hasn't merged his/her changes back to trunk. You just have to use it properly.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot really automate it: even if there are no outright conflicts, the merge might result in non-working code.

two possibilities for future improvements, in increasing order of preference:

one: commit to trunk, have someone appointed to cherry-pick revisions into the release branch

two: switch to mercurial.  srsly.  it's very svn-like, and it's impossible to forget a merge, since merging branch A into branch B means adding into B *all* commits that are in A but not in B

```
# alice edits some files and commits two revisions
# into her repository, then pushes them into the master
alice ~/wc/stable % hg ci
alice ~/wc/stable % hg ci
alice ~/wc/stable % hg push
pushing to http://repo/stable
searching for changes
...

# bobby tries to push, but oops, his copy is stale
bobby ~/wc/stable % hg ci
bobby ~/wc/stable % hg ci
bobby ~/wc/stable % hg ci
bobby ~/wc/stable % hg push
pushing to http://repo/stable
searching for changes
abort: push creates new remote heads!
(did you forget to merge? use push -f to force)

# bobby must augment his repository such that a push
# to the master will leave the master with a single
# head.  this is achieved by pulling changes from
# the master, which will cause *his* repository to have
# two "head" revisions:
bobby ~/wc/stable % hg pull
searching for changes
...
added 2 changesets with 4 changes to 4 files (+1 heads)
(run 'hg heads' to see heads, 'hg merge' to merge)

# he will now merge the heads to reduce them to a single
# head.  pushing that into the master will be ok (since
# the result of such a push is a single head)
bobby ~/wc/stable % hg merge
bobby ~/wc/stable % hg ci
bobby ~/wc/stable % hg push
# ok!
```

you might say this is different from merging between branches, but in mercurial, every working copy is effectively a branch, and both situations are handled with a single set of commands:

```
alice ~/wc/stable % hg ci
alice ~/wc/stable % hg push
alice ~/wc/stable % logout
# alice went home without merging to trunk

bobby ~/wc/stable % hg pull -u
# alice's changeset is now his (only) head
# he edits a file, commits it, and pushes
bobby ~/wc/stable % hg ci
bobby ~/wc/stable % hg push
# his sole commit goes to the master
# the push is ok since it results in a single head
# bobby goes on to merge stable to trunk
bobby ~/wc/stable % cd ../trunk
bobby ~/wc/trunk % hg pull -u
# pulls changes from trunk master
bobby ~/wc/trunk % hg pull http://repo/stable
# pulls all changesets that are in stable but
# not in (this working copy of) trunk
bobby ~/wc/trunk % hg merge
bobby ~/wc/trunk % hg ci
bobby ~/wc/trunk % hg push
```

*this working copy* above is important, but a stale copy won't bite you: if bobby's
working copy was stale WRT the master, the push would fail and prompt him to merge his previous merge with master's new changes before retrying.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this is awfully similar to what we do here, but I'm not aware of any way to currently do this.

Typically, errors like this are caught in our code-review process.

I would wonder what would happen in the case of a merge conflict, and when that happens, how would it get resolved.

Comment: We have a huge code base and we are in a process of finding the missing merges. Doing reintegrate branch gives a list of possible candidates for forgotten merges. However, a lot of the conflicts are just refactoring of code or other major changes in the latter version of the file.

Comment: Sounds to me like you'd want to merge a range of revisions.  Either way, this appears like it will be very manually intensive.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

svnmerge.py will keep track of all your merges for you.

Comment: Since subversion 1.5 there's no longer a need for svnmerge.py. It was used to track merge info in 1.4

Comment: Still needed if you want to merge a branch more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a great idea and I have wanted to implement something similar for some time. My idea so far is to use our CI server to do the merge and then run the build and tests before checking in the result. Fail the CI job if the merge can't be done automatically (which should then notify someone to go do it manually).

With reasonable test coverage, I suspect that the benefits of automating this will outweigh the occasional issue caused by semantically incorrect merging that isn't caught by unit tests. Even that could probably be eliminated by a combination of reviews and failing the job if the portions of code that were merged are not adequately covered by tests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (in addition to the above answer i also recommend svn auto merger project), see this cool project called automerger and it has successfully auto merged hundreds of branches tens of projects and hundred of thousands of commits so far.

you just need to tell it of your projects and from which branch to merge to which for example 1.0.0 --> 1.0.1 --> trunk --> 1.1.0 and as if its a magic every commit to any branch in between will be automatically be merged forwardly.  It will send email notifications for success / faile, update spreadsheet for reporting, csv file for reporting etc and even create jira tickets for failed merges so developers wont forget to merge failed merges by themself

its an opensource here is its link

[svn automerger](https://github.com/liveperson/Auto-Merger)

let me know if you have any questions or any problems starting it up i'll be more than happy to assist!