# SVN: automatic checking if all changes from branch are merged with trunk

Tags: svn, merge, branch, trunk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SVN Automatic merge to branch on check in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808518/svn-automatic-merge-to-branch-on-check-in)

In my teams people usually develop new code in trunk, then we create a branch and the code goes to production. If there are bugs in production they are fixed on branch and then branch is merged with the trunk. And here is the problem. Sometimes it happens that people forget to move all changes from branch to trunk. Yes I know it's strange and shouldn't happen but I wonder if there is a automatic solution to verify if there are pending changes in branch that aren't commited in the trunk. I was thinking about checking the revisions in the trunk and comparing them with the branch but I'm not sure if it is possible. Do you have any idea ?

Thanks for help,
foxrafi

Answer (score 3):

> svn mergeinfo branch trunk --show-revs eligible

It will show which changes were not merged from branch to trunk.

Comment: how does it work with 2 branches? So I have a branch A, branch B, I would like to know if the merge from branch A to merge B was done properly... How Can I do it?